# How to resize an element to full height

Tags: html, css

How to to resize the left-side element?

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/yPqKa/5/

I need to resize an element to full document height.

Thanks in advance.

```
.left-bar {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
.left-bg {
    background-color: #000;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Do you need it to be fixed to left side and are you adding content on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style the left bar this way:

```
.left-bar {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yPqKa/4/)**

Comment: thank you, but if I have a header? How to fix it?

example: http://jsfiddle.net/yPqKa/5/

Comment: Just set the top on the bar to match the header: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yPqKa/6/

Answer (score 0):

Now left bar will start after 75px from top

```
 .left-bar {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
 }
```